# "php comment" within an echo statement

Tags: php, comments

How can I handle comments in the middle of an echo command?

This syntax is getting me a syntax error but why is not compliant?

```
<?
echo "Print this " . /*but not this*/ . " and this\n";
?>
```

Am I forced to write 3 separate statements?

```
<?
echo "Print this "
/*but not this*/
echo " and this\n";
?>
```

Comment: [PHP Docs on comments](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because it resolves to:

```
echo "Print this " .  . " and this\n";
```

Which is a syntax error, so is this:

```
echo "Print this " echo " and this\n";
```

With the exception of inside string literals, comments effectively don't exist in the code upon execution.

Comment: very clear! This is working: <? echo "Print this " . /*but not this*/ " and this\n"; ?>

Answer (score 2):

Include the second (or the first) `.` in the comment:

```
echo "Print this " . /*but not this .*/ " and this\n";
```

That will make it resolve to:

```
echo "Print this " . " and this\n";
```

Comment: This still works. Even works if it's multiple lines and the `. /* comment . */` is on a new line. Cool stuff. Thank you.